# Best practices for implementing asynchronous javascript programming with promise Q library

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, deferred, q

Already had a layer in JS which helps Gets and Posts to the server with the following implementations :

```
var getJson = function(url, callback, onError) {
    $.get(url)
    .done(function(data) {
        if(callback != null)
            callback(data);
    })
    .fail (function(error) {
        if(onError != null)
            onError (error);
        else
            my.notification.notifyError(onErrorMessage);
    });
};

var postJSON = function(url, data, callback, onError) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url ,
        type: "POST" ,
        contentType : "application/json"
        dataType : "json" ,
        date : ko.toJSON(data)
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        if(callback ! = null)
            callback(data);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        if(onError ! = null)
            onError (error);
        else
            my.notification.notifyError(onErrorMessage);
    });
};
```

Using these implementations on DataService layer :

```
// Get
var find = function(date, onSuccess , onError) {
   var url = /* url with the Controller and Action */ + "?queryString = " + data.filter;
   getJson(url , onSuccess , onError);
};

// Post
var save = function(date, onSuccess , onError) {
    var url = /* url with the Controller and Action */;
    postJSON(url, data, onSuccess, onError);
};
```

However we use webapi, wich in some cases, a request depends the result of another request generating a "Pyramid of Doom ". 
For more elegance of code we are implementing the library Q for asynchronous programming.

To follow the pattern shown above using Q promisses was implemented new method of get as show:

```
var getJsonDefer = function(url, callback, onError) {
    return Q.when($.getJSON(url))
    .then (function(data) {
        if(callback ! = null)
            callback(data);
    })
    .fail (function(error) {
        if(onError ! = null)
            onError (error);
        else
            my.notification.notifyError(onErrorMessage);
    });
};
```

I'm trying to use this implementation on DataService layer this way:

```
// Get
var find = function(date, onSuccess , onError) {
   var url = /* url with the Controller and Action */ + "?queryString = " + data.filter;
   return getJsonDefer(url, onSuccess, onError);
};
```

Anyway in my layer viewmodel javascript suppose I need to use 3 finds and one depends on the outcome of the other:

```
var = dataOne { 
    filter: " Filter"
};

findOne(dataOne,
       function(result) {
            return result;
       }
       function(error) {
           throw error;
       })
       .then(function(args) {
            var = datatwo { 
                filter: args
            };

            // Second
            findTwo(datatwo ,
               function(result) {
                    return result;
               }
               function(error) {
                   throw error;
               }
            );
        })
        .then(function(args) {
            var = dataThree { 
                filter: args
            };

            // Third
            findThree(dataThree,
                function(result) {
                    return result;
                }
                function(error) {
                    throw error;
                }
            );
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle any error from all above steps
        })
        .done();
```

My problem :

I admit that I am not able to implement the right way, because all my functions inside .then() are coming with undefined args.

I wonder know what is the best practice to meet the scenario propose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that the appeal of promises is that you can accomplish your goals with much less code that before.  There are a few things you’ll need to know about, though.  For one, you will not need to pass or receive callbacks and errbacks anymore.  You just need to make sure to return results or promises for results in your handlers.  That is how the values propagate to the next handler.

This is an untested adaptation of your program that should illustrate the form:

```
var find = function(data) {
    var url = /* url with the Controller and Action */ + "?queryString = " + data.filter;
    return Q($.getJson(url));
};

find({filter: "filter"})
.then(function (firstResult) {
    return find({filter: firstResult})
    .then(function (secondResult) {
        return find({filter: secondResult})
        .then(function (thirdResult) {
            return [firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult];
        });
    });
})
.fail(notifyError)
.done();
```

Note that an error in any stage will be handled by the single `fail` call at the bottom.  Regardless of whether you have an error handler at the end, always end a chain with `done()` so that any errors that happen before, even in your `fail` handler, show up in your console.

Note that you only need to nest promises if one operation depends on the previous and the handler needs access both the first and second result.  If you only need the result of the second operation, you can just chain.

```
find({filter: "filter"})
.then(function (firstResult) {
    return find({filter: firstResult})
})
.then(function (secondResult) {
    return find({filter: secondResult})
    .then(function (thirdResult) {
        return [secondResult, thirdResult];
    });
});
.fail(notifyError)
.done();
```

You can also flatten things with `Q.all` and `promise.spread`, but I will leave you to the [documentation](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) at this point because, I hope, you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kris. "You just need to make sure to return results or promises for results in your handlers. That is how the values propagate to the next handler." this is the 'trick'. Javascript and its implementations has fascinated me every day. Yes I will continue studying to improve my knowledge.